# SOLR Query works not properly with field starts with

Tags: java, php, search, solr

I am new to Solr, I have developed a grouped search which should group Search results by object_class (each database table is has a object like User, Artist, ...).

Now I was trying to build a search, which should search in fields like headline, subtitle, content and biography.

For each object I have a different search query (because with solr you are not able to implement different sort orders when grouped result).

The Problem: There is an Artist with headline "Cuebrick". Now normally this should be find when searching for Cueb or even headline:Cueb* but this doesn't work.

Like in screenshots you can see I am searching for Cueb, headline:cueb* and headline:cuebrick with object_class:Artist ( ... AND ... ).

Why arent my "like" queries working?

Query: `cueb AND object_class:Artist`

[image: query1 not working]

Query: `headline:cueb* AND object_class:Artist`

[image: query2 not working]

Query: `headline:cuebrick AND object_class:Artist`

[image: query3 the right result]

The important part of my schema looks like this:

```
<field name="headline" type="text_de" indexed="true" stored="true" stripHTML="true" />
(... same for content, subtitle and biography)


<defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>

<copyField source="headline" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="content" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="keywords" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="subtitle" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="biography" dest="text"/>
```

and here my text_de definition (changed it right now, do i have to reindex? restart didnt change anything):

```
<fieldType name="text_de" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_de.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" splitOnCaseChange="1" splitOnNumerics="1" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="German2" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_de.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" splitOnCaseChange="1" splitOnNumerics="1" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="German2" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: Can you share details of field type "text_de". Which analyzers are applied at query and index time???

Comment: @mgs updated right now to schema (see above)

Answer (score 3):

Token "*cuebrick*" will be stored in your index as "*cubrick*" due to filter **class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="German2**".

Your query *headline:cueb** is a wildcard query.
Wildcard query does not perform any analysis on the text you provide as the query. So it will search for token with prefix "cueb" and cant find any match as your indexed token is "*cubrick*".

Change your query to *headline:cub** and check results.

Comment: headline:cub* works fine.. youre right. so removing snowball porter filter should solve the indexing probleme?

Comment: Yes. Please up vote the answer if you find helpful to you.. :)

Comment: Apply only Standard Tokenizer and remove other analyzers. Every word will be stored as it is...